# Text-based vertical scroller game

Tags: c++, performance, game, windows, curses

I'm making a simple text game using the pdCurses library and a few other minor things like a vertical scroller in which you avoid the randomly-generated walls.

There are two walls on left and right made out of 'X' characters and blank, black space in which you can move around and avoid the 'X's your character is an '8' and your forced to continue forward or get touched by the X's each time a new line of the randomly generated "map" is revealed (for performance tests I'm making new lines show as fast as possible).

However, I am having performance issues and need new lines to be inserted and shown at least 3-5 times per second.  Please suggest some simple ways of boosting performance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h> // or "ctime"
#include <stdio.h> // for 
#include <cstdlib> 
// Windows stuff
#include <Windows.h> // GOD DAMMNIT WINDOWS WHY????
#include <conio.h>
// Ncurses
#include<curses.h>
// STL stuff
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
//String/Int conversion
#include <sstream>
// gives access to rand function
#include <cstdlib>
//gives access to time functions
#include <ctime>

// mySTOPWATCH   i think i'm gonna cry.... =')
#include <myStopwatch.h> // for keeping times
#include <myMath.h>      // numb_digits() and digit_val();
using namespace std;
enum{ NUMB_LINES= 24, SEC= 1000};                   // time stuff
enum{TIME= 345, HEALTH = 346, MAP= 247};    // for Refresh() command
enum{NONE= 256};                                    // for Refresh() transition
enum{NEW = 590, OLD = 591};                         // for the old/new screen command

// Some nCurses setup
 int r = 0,
     c = 0; // current row and column (upper-left is (0,0))
 const int nrows = 56, // number of rows in window
           ncols = 79; // number of columns in window
// Timer Setup
 Stopwatch myStopwatch(3, START);

 ///////////////////////////        RandNumb()  ///////////////////////////////////////
int RandNumb(int scope){
    srand(GetTickCount());
    return rand() % scope;};
//////////////////////////      GeneratePathStart() ///////////////////////////////
void GeneratePathStart(vector<string>& buff){
    int wall= RandNumb(80)/2, 
        space = (RandNumb(75)/2)+5,
        wall2= 80- (wall+space);
    buff.push_back("");
    for(;wall> 0; wall--){
        buff[0].push_back('X');}
    for(;space> 0; space--){
        buff[0].push_back(' ');}
    for(; wall2 > 0; wall2--){
        buff[0].push_back('X');}
    };

//////////////////////////      GeneratePath()  ////////////////////////////////////
void GeneratePath( vector<string>& buff){// the buff is the seed  too
    int wall= RandNumb(80)/2, 
        space = (RandNumb(75)/2)+5,
        wall2= 80-(space+wall);
    int swall= 0;
        for(char i= '0'; i!= ' ';swall++)
            i= buff[buff.size()-1][swall+1];
    int sspace= 0; int I= swall+1;
        for(char i= '0'; i!= 'X';sspace++, I++)
            i= buff[buff.size()-1][I];
    int swall2 = 80-(sspace+swall);

    // now the actual generation
    int cwall= wall-swall; 
    int cspace= space-sspace; 
    int cwall2= wall2-swall2;
    for(;cwall!= 0 || cspace!= 0 /*|| cwall2 != 0*/;){
            buff.push_back("");
//cwall
            if(cwall!= 0){
                if(cwall>0){
                    swall++;
                    cwall--;}
                else{ // cwall is negative
                    swall--;
                    cwall++;}}
            for(int w= 0; w <swall; w++)
                buff[buff.size()-1].push_back('X');
// cspace
            if(cspace!= 0){
                if(cspace>0){
                    sspace++;
                    cspace--;}
                else{ // cspace is negative
                    sspace--;
                    cspace++;}}
            for(int s= 0; s <sspace; s++)
                buff[buff.size()-1].push_back(' ');
// cwall2
            //if(cwall2!= 0){               
            //  if(cwall2>0){
            //      wall2++;
            //      cwall2--;}
            //  else{ // cspace is negative
            //      wall2--;
            //      cwall2++;}}
            for(int w2= 0; w2 <80- (swall+sspace); w2++)
                buff[buff.size()-1].push_back('X');
    }}// end of function

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////    Sprite Class    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Sprite
{

private:
    string name;
    char symbol;
    float health;
    int location[2];

public:
///////////////////// Get and SET all the privates  ///////
    Sprite(){};
    Sprite(string a_name, char a_symbol, float a_health){
        name = a_name;
        symbol = a_symbol;
        health = a_health;};

    char get_symbol() {return symbol;};
    void set_symbol(char sym) {symbol = sym;};

    float get_health() {return health;};
    void set_health(float numb) {health = numb;};
    void add_health (float numb) {health += numb;};

    string get_name() {return name;};
    string set_name(string aName) {name = aName;};

    int* get_location(){return location;};
    void set_location(int X, int Y) {
        location[0] = X;
        location[1] = Y;};

////////////////////////////////    Move    ////////////
    bool move(int X, int Y) {
                location[0] += X;
                location[1] += Y;
                return true;};
};// end of sprite


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////   Player Class    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Player : public Sprite
{
public:
    Player(string name,int X, int Y, float health){
        set_symbol('8');
        set_name(name);
        set_location(X,Y);
        set_health(100);};
private:
    // none?

};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////      Map class   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Map
{
private:
///////////////////////////////////////////     Map Variables ///////////////
    string name;
    vector <string> contents;
    vector <string> save;

public:
    Map(){};
    Map(string* lines, int i, string name= "map"){name = name;
                                           contents.resize(56);
                                           Insert(lines, i);};
    ~Map(){};

///////////////////////////////////////////     generate    ////////////////////
    void generate(){GeneratePath(contents);};
///////////////////////////////////////////     Return()    ////////////////////
    string Name()               {return name;};
    vector <string> Contents()  {return contents;};
    string Contents(int Y)      {return contents[Y];};
    char Contents(int Y, int X) {return contents[Y][X];};
    vector <string> Save()      {return save;};
    int size()                  {return contents.size();};

///////////////////////////////////////////     Insert()    ////////////////////
            //  string* to an array of 24 strings;
    void Insert(string* lines, int i)            
    {contents.assign(lines, lines+i);}; //insert lines 1-24

    void Insert(string astring, int Y)   {contents[Y] = astring;};

    void Insert(char achar, int X, int Y){contents[Y][X] = achar;};

    void Saveline(string line)           {save.push_back(line);}; 
};

/////////////////////////   SCREEN CLASS        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Screen
{
private:
///////////////////////////////////////////     Screen Variables ///////////////
    string _name;
    vector <string> new_map;
    vector <string> old_map;
    vector <Sprite*> sprites_p;

public:
    Screen(string name){_name = name;
                        new_map.resize(nrows);
                        old_map.resize(nrows);};
    ~Screen(){};

////////////////////////////////////////////    Get contents    ///////////////////////////
    vector <string> get_contents(int comm= NEW)              {switch(comm){ case NEW: return new_map; break;
                                                                            case OLD: return old_map; break;}};
    string get_contents         (int Y, int comm= NEW)       {switch(comm){ case NEW: return new_map[Y]; break;
                                                                            case OLD: return old_map[Y]; break;}};
    char get_contents           (int X, int Y, int comm= NEW){switch(comm){ case NEW: return new_map[Y][X]; break;
                                                                            case OLD: return old_map[Y][X]; break;}};

////////////////////////////////////////////    Refresh     ///////////////////////////
void Refresh(int command= ALL, int transition= NONE)
{
    //old_map = new_map;    // update the old map
    for(int r= 0; r< nrows; r++){ move(r,0); 
                                  addstr((char*)new_map[r].c_str());}                   // make sure this works later
    // Insert Time 
    if(command== ALL || command== TIME){
    enum{ time_loc_y= 22, 
          time_loc_x= 38 };
    mvaddstr(time_loc_y, time_loc_x, myStopwatch.ClockTime().c_str());}

refresh();}; // end of function

///////////////////////////////////////////     Insert  ////////////////////////
                                                            /////////////////// Map
    void Insert(Map& map, int y1, int y2)   {for ( int mc = y1, nm= 0; mc< map.size() && mc< y2; mc++, nm++){
                                                new_map[nm] = map.Contents(mc);}
    };
                                                            /////////////////// string
    void Insert(string astring, int Y)      {new_map[Y] = astring;};
                                                            ///////////////////// char
    void Insert(char achar, int X, int Y)   {new_map[Y][X] = achar;};
                                                            ////////////////////  sprite
    void Insert(Sprite& sprite)         {new_map[sprite.get_location()[1]][sprite.get_location()[0]] = sprite.get_symbol();
                                         sprites_p.push_back(&sprite);};    // save a pointer to the sprite

///////////////////////////////////////////     Collision Detection ///////////
    bool check_collision(Sprite& sprite,int X, int Y, char& buff) 
    {
    ////////////////////// check whats already there /////
        char newloc = new_map[sprite.get_location()[1]+Y]
                             [sprite.get_location()[0]+X];
        if(newloc == '|' || newloc == '/' || newloc == '_' || newloc == '=' || newloc == 'X' || newloc == '-' || newloc == 'x' ) {buff = newloc; return true;}

        else return false;
    };
};


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////   MAIN    ////////////////////////////////////  MAIN  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
cout << "make the screen fullscreen!!";
char response; cin >> response;

    WINDOW *wnd;
 wnd = initscr(); // curses call to initialize window and curses mode
 //cbreak(); // curses call to set no waiting for Enter key
 noecho(); // curses call to set no echoing
 //curs_set(a number); (0 = invisible, 1 = normal, 2 = very visible)
 int row,col; getmaxyx(stdscr,row,col);     /* get the number of rows and columns */
 clear(); // curses call to clear screen, send cursor to position (0,0)

 Screen theScreen("ascreen");

        string splashScreen[24] = {    // HERE"S THE SPLASH !
//                    1        2        3       4        5         6        7        8        
//                         123456789         123456789         123456789         123456789
//               0123456789         123456789         123456789         123456789         1234567
/* 0 */         "________________________________________________________________________________", 
/* 1 */         "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|",  
/* 2 */         "|XXXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 3 */         "|XXXXXX  /  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     xXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXXXx  xXXXXXXx  xXXX|", 
/* 4 */         "|XXXXX  /0}  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   /XXXXx  XXXXXXx /X xXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXX    XXX|", 
/* 5 */         "|XXXX  /000}  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX   /XXXXXXXx  XXXXX  /X  XXXXXXXX  /X  XXXX  /X  XX|", 
/* 6 */         "|XXX           XXXXXXXXXXXX   /XXXXXXXXxx XXXX  /XXX  XXXXXXX /XX  XXXX  |X  XX|", 
/* 7 */         "|XX   /XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXX   /XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  /XXX  XXXXXX  |XXX  XX   /X  xX|", 
/* 8 */         "|X   /XXXXXXXX   X*X*X*XXX  /XXXXx        xXX          XXXXX  |XXX      /XXX  X|", 
/* 9 */         "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXX   XX  /XXXXX  XXXX   |XXXX    /XXXX  X|", 
/* 10 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXXX    Xx /XXXXXXX xXXX   |XXXXx  /XXXX   X|", 
/* 11*/         "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX            XXXx /XXXXXXX xXX     XXXXXxxXXXX    x|", 
/* 12 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 13 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxXXXX|", 
/* 14 */        "|XXX  XXxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                  XXX|", 
/* 15 */        "|XXX  XXXx  XX/  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_____XX     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 16 */        "|XXX    XXX  /  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 17 */        "|XXX /0] XX/  XXXXx      xXX  XXXXXXXXXXX    xXXX    xXXXX                 xXXX|", 
/* 18 */        "|XXX    XX/  XXXXX  XXXXXXXX    xXXX  XXX  XXXXXX  XXXXXXX                 xXXX|", 
/* 19 */        "|XXXXXXXX  XXXXXXX  XXx  xXX  XXXXXX  XXX    xXXX    xXXXX     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 20 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXX  XX  XXXXXX  XXX  XXXXXX  XXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 21 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx      xXXxxXXXXXXxxXXX xXXXXXX xXXXXXXX                  XXX|", 
/* 22 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxXXX|", 
/* 23 */        "|______________________________________________________________________________|",};

    string _lines_[56] = {   
//                    1        2        3       4        5         6        7        8        
//                         123456789         123456789         123456789         123456789
//               0123456789         123456789         123456789         123456789         1234567
/* 0 */         "________________________________________________________________________________", 
/* 1 */         "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|",  
/* 2 */         "|XXXXXXXX                    XXXXXXXXXXXXX              XXXXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 3 */         "|XXXXX                 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 4 */         "|XXXX      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 5 */         "|XXX      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 6 */         "|XX       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 7 */         "|XX       XXXXXXXX           XXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 8 */         "|XXX       XXXXXXXXXX         XXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 9 */         "|XXXX        XXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 10 */        "|XXXXX        XXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 11 */        "|XXXXXXX        XXXXXXXXX     XXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 12 */        "|XXXXXXXX        XXXXXXX      XXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 13 */        "|XXXXXXXXXX       XXXXX       XXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXX___XXXXXXXX|",
/* 14 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXX                XXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXxxxXXXXXXXX|",
/* 15 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXX              XXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXx   xXXXXXXX|",
/* 16 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX              XXXXXXXXXXXx   xXXXXXXX|",
/* 17 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|",
/* 18 */        "|______________________________________________________________________________|",
/* 19 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|",
/* 20 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|",
/* 21 */        "|XXX                                                                        XXX|",
/* 22 */        "|XXX                                                                        XXX|",
/* 23 */        "|XXX                                                                        XXX|",
/* 0 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 1 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|",  
/* 2 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 3 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 4 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 5 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 6 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 7 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 8 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 9 */         "|XXXX                                                                      XXXX|", 
/* 10 */        "|XXXXX                                                                    XXXXX|", 
/* 11*/         "|XXXXXX                                                                  XXXXXX|", 
/* 12 */        "|XXXXXXX                                                                XXXXXXX|", 
/* 13 */        "|XXXXXXXX                                                              XXXXXXXX|", 
/* 14 */        "|XXXXXXXXX                                                            XXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 15 */        "|XXXXXXXXXX                                                          XXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 16 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXX                                                        XXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 17 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXX                                                        XXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 18 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXX                                                      XXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 19 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXX                                                      XXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 20 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                    XXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 21 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                    XXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 22 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 23 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX|"
/* 24 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 25 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 26 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 27 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 28 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 29 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                              XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 30 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 31*/         "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 32 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
};    

    //////////////////////////////////  Splash Screen   /////////////////////////////   
    Map splashScreen_map(splashScreen, 24);
    theScreen.Insert(splashScreen_map, 0, nrows);
    theScreen.Refresh(MAP);
    myStopwatch.Wait(3);
    myStopwatch.Restart();
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    Map L1(_lines_, nrows, "L1");
    theScreen.Insert(L1, 0, nrows);
    Sprite player("Player",'8',100);   //(8, 12, 16);
    player.set_location(24, 48);

    ////////////////////// Check if new line is needed;
    double refreshes= 0;
    double newSpeed= 10;
    for (bool quit = false; quit != true;)
    {   double newTime= myStopwatch.ElapsedTime()- refreshes;
        if(newTime*newSpeed >= 1){
            theScreen.Insert(L1, 0+refreshes, nrows+refreshes);
            refreshes++;
            if(L1.size()<= nrows+refreshes+2)
                L1.generate();}
    /////////////////   Keypress    ///////////
        if (kbhit()){
        int key = getch(); 
        key = toupper(key); // makes whatever key uppercase

                        int xMove = 0;
                        int yMove = 0;
                        int stepSize = 1;
                        bool validPress = true;
        switch(key){
    // update health here............
        case 'W': yMove = -stepSize;break;
        case 'S': yMove = stepSize; break;
        case 'A': xMove = -stepSize;break;
        case 'D': xMove = stepSize; break;

        case'P': getch();           break;
        case'O': quit = true;

        default: validPress = false;}

            if(validPress == true){

                char coll;                          // if there's no collision
                if(theScreen.check_collision(player, xMove, yMove, coll) != true){ 
                    // get rid of old player placing
                    theScreen.Insert(' ', player.get_location()[0],player.get_location()[1]);
                    // put in new charater placing
                    player.move(xMove, yMove);
                    theScreen.Insert(player);
                    theScreen.Refresh();}
                else{
                    theScreen.Refresh();}};
                    // do other stuff with 'coll';

        } /* end of if(kbhit())*/ 

        theScreen.Refresh();}// so refresh and restart the for loop

endwin(); // curses call to restore the original window and leave
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h> // or "ctime"
#include <stdio.h> // for
```

Its best to avoid useless noise comments which contribute nothing

```
#include <cstdlib> 
// Windows stuff
#include <Windows.h> // GOD DAMMNIT WINDOWS WHY????
```

As fun as complaining about Windows is, it is distracting to have comments like this. Have your comments tell me about what is going on, not your complaints about Microsoft.

```
#include <conio.h>
// Ncurses
#include<curses.h>
// STL stuff
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
//String/Int conversion
#include <sstream>
// gives access to rand function
#include <cstdlib>
//gives access to time functions
#include <ctime>

// mySTOPWATCH   i think i'm gonna cry.... =')
```

Again, not a substantive comment

```
#include <myStopwatch.h> // for keeping times
#include <myMath.h>      // numb_digits() and digit_val();
using namespace std;
enum{ NUMB_LINES= 24, SEC= 1000};                   // time stuff
enum{TIME= 345, HEALTH = 346, MAP= 247};    // for Refresh() command
enum{NONE= 256};                                    // for Refresh() transition
enum{NEW = 590, OLD = 591};                         // for the old/new screen command

// Some nCurses setup
 int r = 0,
     c = 0; // current row and column (upper-left is (0,0))
```

If you want to split the assignment onto two lines, just make it two statements. Also I suggest using row and column or x,y because r/c aren't quite common enough that its obvious what they mean.

```
 const int nrows = 56, // number of rows in window
           ncols = 79; // number of columns in window
// Timer Setup
 Stopwatch myStopwatch(3, START);


 ///////////////////////////        RandNumb()  ///////////////////////////////////////
int RandNumb(int scope){
    srand(GetTickCount());
    return rand() % scope;};
```

Many commonly used formatting rules exist. I'm not aware of any which put the } on the same line as the final statement. Also, srand should be called exactly once at the start of your program not every time you want a random number. There is also no need for the final semicolon.

```
//////////////////////////      GeneratePathStart() ///////////////////////////////
```

Some people do comments like this. I think they are silly because if I wanted to know the function's name I'd have read the function's name in the code.

```
void GeneratePathStart(vector<string>& buff){
    int wall= RandNumb(80)/2,
```

Ok, why don't you use RandNumb(40)?

```
        space = (RandNumb(75)/2)+5,
        wall2= 80- (wall+space);
```

I'm really not a fan of multiple assignments like this. it makes me hunt to try and figure out they are ints. Also, its best to adopt a consistent spacing regimine. I recommond putting spaces around all binary operators.

```
    buff.push_back("");
    for(;wall> 0; wall--){
        buff[0].push_back('X');}
```

Counting down is unusual. You don't have any reason to do it here, so I recommend counting up. Otherwise its just seems odd. odd is bad.

```
    for(;space> 0; space--){
        buff[0].push_back(' ');}
    for(; wall2 > 0; wall2--){
        buff[0].push_back('X');}
    };

//////////////////////////      GeneratePath()  ////////////////////////////////////
void GeneratePath( vector<string>& buff){// the buff is the seed  too
    int wall= RandNumb(80)/2, 
        space = (RandNumb(75)/2)+5,
        wall2= 80-(space+wall);
    int swall= 0;
        for(char i= '0'; i!= ' ';swall++)
            i= buff[buff.size()-1][swall+1];
```

Its really really important that you put all statements  in the same block as the same level as each other. Otherwise you WILL introduce bugs.

```
    int sspace= 0; int I= swall+1;
```

This I is a really bad variable name because it provides no hints as to what it does.

```
        for(char i= '0'; i!= 'X';sspace++, I++)
            i= buff[buff.size()-1][I];
```

For loops are best for simple iterations. Here you're doing a bunch of crazy stuff which makes it hard to follow what the loop is doing. A while loop can do this cleaner.

```
    int swall2 = 80-(sspace+swall);
```

Variable names like swall2 suggest you were too lazy to come up with a better variable name. Come up with a more descriptive one.

```
    // now the actual generation
    int cwall= wall-swall; 
    int cspace= space-sspace; 
    int cwall2= wall2-swall2;
    for(;cwall!= 0 || cspace!= 0 /*|| cwall2 != 0*/;){
            buff.push_back("");
//cwall
```

Comments are not for pieces of old code. They are for explanation. Right about now I have no idea what this piece of code is doing. Some comments explaining your algorithm or at least some meaningful variable names would be good.

```
            if(cwall!= 0){
                if(cwall>0){
                    swall++;
                    cwall--;}
                else{ // cwall is negative
                    swall--;
                    cwall++;}}
            for(int w= 0; w <swall; w++)
                buff[buff.size()-1].push_back('X');
// cspace
            if(cspace!= 0){
                if(cspace>0){
                    sspace++;
                    cspace--;}
                else{ // cspace is negative
                    sspace--;
                    cspace++;}}
            for(int s= 0; s <sspace; s++)
                buff[buff.size()-1].push_back(' ');
// cwall2
            //if(cwall2!= 0){               
            //  if(cwall2>0){
            //      wall2++;
            //      cwall2--;}
            //  else{ // cspace is negative
            //      wall2--;
            //      cwall2++;}}
            for(int w2= 0; w2 <80- (swall+sspace); w2++)
                buff[buff.size()-1].push_back('X');
    }}// end of function

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////    Sprite Class    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Seriously... do you think all those / help?

```
class Sprite
{

private:
    string name;
    char symbol;
    float health;
    int location[2];

public:
///////////////////// Get and SET all the privates  ///////
    Sprite(){};
    Sprite(string a_name, char a_symbol, float a_health){
        name = a_name;
        symbol = a_symbol;
        health = a_health;};

    char get_symbol() {return symbol;};
    void set_symbol(char sym) {symbol = sym;};

    float get_health() {return health;};
    void set_health(float numb) {health = numb;};
    void add_health (float numb) {health += numb;};

    string get_name() {return name;};
    string set_name(string aName) {name = aName;};

    int* get_location(){return location;};
    void set_location(int X, int Y) {
        location[0] = X;
        location[1] = Y;};
```

Getters and setters are bad. But you probably haven't been coding long enough to worry about that. But seriously, unless someone is making you I suggest directly access the data for now. Don't worry about encapsulation until you've got the complete hang of things. (I'd probably get in trouble for saying that, but nobody is going to read this far)

```
////////////////////////////////    Move    ////////////
    bool move(int X, int Y) {
                location[0] += X;
                location[1] += Y;
                return true;};
```

A function like this is good because it provides a higher level interface, not requiring external objects to deal with getters/setters.

```
};// end of sprite


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////   Player Class    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Player : public Sprite
{
public:
    Player(string name,int X, int Y, float health){
        set_symbol('8');
        set_name(name);
        set_location(X,Y);
        set_health(100);};
private:
    // none?

};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////      Map class   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Map
{
private:
///////////////////////////////////////////     Map Variables ///////////////
```

Again useless comment noise. Assume the reader knows the language.

```
    string name;
    vector <string> contents;
    vector <string> save;
```

I suggest not using string to hold a map. A map isn't text. Better to use enums.

```
public:
    Map(){};
    Map(string* lines, int i, string name= "map"){name = name;
                                           contents.resize(56);
                                           Insert(lines, i);};
    ~Map(){};

///////////////////////////////////////////     generate    ////////////////////
    void generate(){GeneratePath(contents);};
///////////////////////////////////////////     Return()    ////////////////////
    string Name()               {return name;};
    vector <string> Contents()  {return contents;};
    string Contents(int Y)      {return contents[Y];};
    char Contents(int Y, int X) {return contents[Y][X];};
    vector <string> Save()      {return save;};
    int size()                  {return contents.size();};

///////////////////////////////////////////     Insert()    ////////////////////
            //  string* to an array of 24 strings;
    void Insert(string* lines, int i)            
    {contents.assign(lines, lines+i);}; //insert lines 1-24

    void Insert(string astring, int Y)   {contents[Y] = astring;};

    void Insert(char achar, int X, int Y){contents[Y][X] = achar;};

    void Saveline(string line)           {save.push_back(line);}; 
};

/////////////////////////   SCREEN CLASS        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Screen
{
private:
///////////////////////////////////////////     Screen Variables ///////////////
    string _name;
    vector <string> new_map;
    vector <string> old_map;
```

Its odd that you have a Map class but hold everything with strings here.

```
    vector <Sprite*> sprites_p;

public:
    Screen(string name){_name = name;
                        new_map.resize(nrows);
                        old_map.resize(nrows);};
    ~Screen(){};

////////////////////////////////////////////    Get contents    ///////////////////////////
    vector <string> get_contents(int comm= NEW)              {switch(comm){ case NEW: return new_map; break;
                                                                            case OLD: return old_map; break;}};
    string get_contents         (int Y, int comm= NEW)       {switch(comm){ case NEW: return new_map[Y]; break;
                                                                            case OLD: return old_map[Y]; break;}};
    char get_contents           (int X, int Y, int comm= NEW){switch(comm){ case NEW: return new_map[Y][X]; break;
                                                                            case OLD: return old_map[Y][X]; break;}};

////////////////////////////////////////////    Refresh     ///////////////////////////
void Refresh(int command= ALL, int transition= NONE)
{
    //old_map = new_map;    // update the old map
    for(int r= 0; r< nrows; r++){ move(r,0);
```

Please don't put more then the for loop on that line. Its makes it hard to follow.

```
                                  addstr((char*)new_map[r].c_str());}                   // make sure this works later
    // Insert Time 
    if(command== ALL || command== TIME){
    enum{ time_loc_y= 22, 
          time_loc_x= 38 };
    mvaddstr(time_loc_y, time_loc_x, myStopwatch.ClockTime().c_str());}

refresh();}; // end of function

///////////////////////////////////////////     Insert  ////////////////////////
                                                            /////////////////// Map
    void Insert(Map& map, int y1, int y2)   {for ( int mc = y1, nm= 0; mc< map.size() && mc< y2; mc++, nm++){
                                                new_map[nm] = map.Contents(mc);}
    };
                                                            /////////////////// string
    void Insert(string astring, int Y)      {new_map[Y] = astring;};
                                                            ///////////////////// char
    void Insert(char achar, int X, int Y)   {new_map[Y][X] = achar;};
                                                            ////////////////////  sprite
    void Insert(Sprite& sprite)         {new_map[sprite.get_location()[1]][sprite.get_location()[0]] = sprite.get_symbol();
                                         sprites_p.push_back(&sprite);};    // save a pointer to the sprite

///////////////////////////////////////////     Collision Detection ///////////
    bool check_collision(Sprite& sprite,int X, int Y, char& buff) 
    {
    ////////////////////// check whats already there /////
        char newloc = new_map[sprite.get_location()[1]+Y]
                             [sprite.get_location()[0]+X];
        if(newloc == '|' || newloc == '/' || newloc == '_' || newloc == '=' || newloc == 'X' || newloc == '-' || newloc == 'x' ) {buff = newloc; return true;}
```

Here is where using enums would help. The code would make it clear what its saying. Right now we just have a bunch of crazy symbols.

```
        else return false;
    };
};


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////   MAIN    ////////////////////////////////////  MAIN  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Hmm... doubly main.

```
int main()
{
cout << "make the screen fullscreen!!";
char response; cin >> response;
```

Don't put multiple statements on the same line, there isn't any reason and it odd.

```
    WINDOW *wnd;
 wnd = initscr(); // curses call to initialize window and curses mode
 //cbreak(); // curses call to set no waiting for Enter key
 noecho(); // curses call to set no echoing
 //curs_set(a number); (0 = invisible, 1 = normal, 2 = very visible)
 int row,col; getmaxyx(stdscr,row,col);     /* get the number of rows and columns */
 clear(); // curses call to clear screen, send cursor to position (0,0)

 Screen theScreen("ascreen");

        string splashScreen[24] = {    // HERE"S THE SPLASH !
//                    1        2        3       4        5         6        7        8        
//                         123456789         123456789         123456789         123456789
//               0123456789         123456789         123456789         123456789         1234567
/* 0 */         "________________________________________________________________________________", 
/* 1 */         "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|",  
/* 2 */         "|XXXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 3 */         "|XXXXXX  /  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     xXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXXXx  xXXXXXXx  xXXX|", 
/* 4 */         "|XXXXX  /0}  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   /XXXXx  XXXXXXx /X xXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXX    XXX|", 
/* 5 */         "|XXXX  /000}  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX   /XXXXXXXx  XXXXX  /X  XXXXXXXX  /X  XXXX  /X  XX|", 
/* 6 */         "|XXX           XXXXXXXXXXXX   /XXXXXXXXxx XXXX  /XXX  XXXXXXX /XX  XXXX  |X  XX|", 
/* 7 */         "|XX   /XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXX   /XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  /XXX  XXXXXX  |XXX  XX   /X  xX|", 
/* 8 */         "|X   /XXXXXXXX   X*X*X*XXX  /XXXXx        xXX          XXXXX  |XXX      /XXX  X|", 
/* 9 */         "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXX   XX  /XXXXX  XXXX   |XXXX    /XXXX  X|", 
/* 10 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXXX    Xx /XXXXXXX xXXX   |XXXXx  /XXXX   X|", 
/* 11*/         "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX            XXXx /XXXXXXX xXX     XXXXXxxXXXX    x|", 
/* 12 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 13 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxXXXX|", 
/* 14 */        "|XXX  XXxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                  XXX|", 
/* 15 */        "|XXX  XXXx  XX/  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_____XX     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 16 */        "|XXX    XXX  /  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 17 */        "|XXX /0] XX/  XXXXx      xXX  XXXXXXXXXXX    xXXX    xXXXX                 xXXX|", 
/* 18 */        "|XXX    XX/  XXXXX  XXXXXXXX    xXXX  XXX  XXXXXX  XXXXXXX                 xXXX|", 
/* 19 */        "|XXXXXXXX  XXXXXXX  XXx  xXX  XXXXXX  XXX    xXXX    xXXXX     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 20 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXX  XX  XXXXXX  XXX  XXXXXX  XXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 21 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx      xXXxxXXXXXXxxXXX xXXXXXX xXXXXXXX                  XXX|", 
/* 22 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxXXX|", 
/* 23 */        "|______________________________________________________________________________|",};

    string _lines_[56] = {   
//                    1        2        3       4        5         6        7        8        
//                         123456789         123456789         123456789         123456789
//               0123456789         123456789         123456789         123456789         1234567
/* 0 */         "________________________________________________________________________________", 
/* 1 */         "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|",  
/* 2 */         "|XXXXXXXX                    XXXXXXXXXXXXX              XXXXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 3 */         "|XXXXX                 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 4 */         "|XXXX      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 5 */         "|XXX      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 6 */         "|XX       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 7 */         "|XX       XXXXXXXX           XXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 8 */         "|XXX       XXXXXXXXXX         XXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 9 */         "|XXXX        XXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 10 */        "|XXXXX        XXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 11 */        "|XXXXXXX        XXXXXXXXX     XXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 12 */        "|XXXXXXXX        XXXXXXX      XXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 13 */        "|XXXXXXXXXX       XXXXX       XXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXX___XXXXXXXX|",
/* 14 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXX                XXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXxxxXXXXXXXX|",
/* 15 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXX              XXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXx   xXXXXXXX|",
/* 16 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX              XXXXXXXXXXXx   xXXXXXXX|",
/* 17 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|",
/* 18 */        "|______________________________________________________________________________|",
/* 19 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|",
/* 20 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|",
/* 21 */        "|XXX                                                                        XXX|",
/* 22 */        "|XXX                                                                        XXX|",
/* 23 */        "|XXX                                                                        XXX|",
/* 0 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 1 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|",  
/* 2 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 3 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 4 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 5 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 6 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 7 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 8 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 9 */         "|XXXX                                                                      XXXX|", 
/* 10 */        "|XXXXX                                                                    XXXXX|", 
/* 11*/         "|XXXXXX                                                                  XXXXXX|", 
/* 12 */        "|XXXXXXX                                                                XXXXXXX|", 
/* 13 */        "|XXXXXXXX                                                              XXXXXXXX|", 
/* 14 */        "|XXXXXXXXX                                                            XXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 15 */        "|XXXXXXXXXX                                                          XXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 16 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXX                                                        XXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 17 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXX                                                        XXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 18 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXX                                                      XXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 19 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXX                                                      XXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 20 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                    XXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 21 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                    XXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 22 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 23 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX|"
/* 24 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 25 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 26 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 27 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 28 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 29 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                              XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 30 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 31*/         "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 32 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
};
```

I recommend putting big things like this in a global variable or external file. That way your code isn't cluttered.

```
    //////////////////////////////////  Splash Screen   /////////////////////////////   
    Map splashScreen_map(splashScreen, 24);
    theScreen.Insert(splashScreen_map, 0, nrows);
    theScreen.Refresh(MAP);
    myStopwatch.Wait(3);
    myStopwatch.Restart();
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    Map L1(_lines_, nrows, "L1");
    theScreen.Insert(L1, 0, nrows);
    Sprite player("Player",'8',100);   //(8, 12, 16);
    player.set_location(24, 48);

    ////////////////////// Check if new line is needed;
    double refreshes= 0;
    double newSpeed= 10;
    for (bool quit = false; quit != true;)
    {   double newTime= myStopwatch.ElapsedTime()- refreshes;
```

I've probably already said it, but adopt a consistent strategy for where you put your braces.

```
        if(newTime*newSpeed >= 1){
            theScreen.Insert(L1, 0+refreshes, nrows+refreshes);
            refreshes++;
            if(L1.size()<= nrows+refreshes+2)
                L1.generate();}
    /////////////////   Keypress    ///////////
        if (kbhit()){
        int key = getch(); 
        key = toupper(key); // makes whatever key uppercase

                        int xMove = 0;
                        int yMove = 0;
                        int stepSize = 1;
                        bool validPress = true;
        switch(key){
    // update health here............
        case 'W': yMove = -stepSize;break;
        case 'S': yMove = stepSize; break;
        case 'A': xMove = -stepSize;break;
        case 'D': xMove = stepSize; break;

        case'P': getch();           break;
        case'O': quit = true;

        default: validPress = false;}

            if(validPress == true){

                char coll;                          // if there's no collision
                if(theScreen.check_collision(player, xMove, yMove, coll) != true){ 
                    // get rid of old player placing
                    theScreen.Insert(' ', player.get_location()[0],player.get_location()[1]);
                    // put in new charater placing
                    player.move(xMove, yMove);
                    theScreen.Insert(player);
                    theScreen.Refresh();}
                else{
                    theScreen.Refresh();}};
                    // do other stuff with 'coll';

        } /* end of if(kbhit())*/ 

        theScreen.Refresh();}// so refresh and restart the for loop

endwin(); // curses call to restore the original window and leave
return 0;
}
```

Altogether pretty good for someone who only has two months of coding expierence. However, you really wanted help on speed and nothing jumped out at me as problematic. (Mind you, I was lost for what most of the code was doing).

At this point what you need is a profiler. I don't know what compiler/IDE you are using so I can't tell you how to do it. Essentially, a profiler will help you narrow down which part of the code is problematic. I'd run mine but your code doesn't even come close to compiling on my linux box.

Comment: Assuming 2 months coding experience of OP literally means they started programming for the first time in their life then using a profiler may be quite a bit tricky, but that's just my opinion. Second, if this is a homework question by any chance, then those extra comments, that I agree are noise as well, are what keeps a TA deducting marks from the project on the grounds of "Code was not commented properly". This has been my experience with TAs/markers (it is quite sad, I agree, but nothing can be done about it). +1 for a thorough breakdown.